# I'll never have any questions

Tags: discussion

All I want to do is be able to upvote good answers and write answers/comments of my own... practically every question I've already had has been asked.

How can I build a reputation?

Comment: Most people get most of their reputation by answering questions, not by asking them.

Comment: You get more points for an upvoted answer than an upvoted question too. So I foresee no problems building a reputation.

Comment: My questions have all come from genuine problems I've had - I've not tried to think of questions that will get me points. So, if you do programming professionally (or a spare-time programming project) you should come up against hard problems every now and again. There's always new ones to be posted.

Answer (score 6):

By correcting spelling, fixing grammar, and also answering questions, not asking them.